# Tableau - Extract Size on Disk 100x Larger than "Stats for Space Usage" Admin Viz Shows

Tags: tableau-api

I was about to upgrade from 10.4 to 10.5.3 when I saw that the drive that we installed Tableau onto was almost full - 115GB out of 127GB was used. I ran `tabadmin cleanup` and now it is at 110GB used.

I searched to see what was using the space and `"T:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\data\tabsvc\dataengine\extract\"` is consuming 100GB. I checked on the `"Stats for Space Usage"` across all sites and all datasource extracts come to about 900MB. Adding in some workbooks that have been saved as .TWBX files as it comes to less than 1GB across all sites.

1. What is the cause of this discrepancy please?
2. What is consuming this space?
3. How do I recover this space?

I am postponing my upgrade in order to have sufficient space so that the upgrade doesn't fail. I am also concerned about the server crashing should it run out of space - I am quite glad that I caught this issue in time!!

After the initial `tabadmin cleanup` I executed the following commands, but they haven't helped:

1. tabadmin cleanup
2. tabadmin stop
3. tabadmin clearcache
4. tabadmin cleanup
5. tabadmin start

Thank you
Andrew

---

**Clarification:** Where the space is used:

The directory in question.
[image: The directory in question.]

The details of the data extract directory. There are 256 sub-directories, from 00 to FF.
[image: The details of the data extract directory. There are 256 sub-directories, from 00 to FF.]

Comment: Did you run the cleanup whlist running the server or after you stopped ?

Comment: @PirateX Both before and after I stopped the server.

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons for this -

1. When you run `tabadmin cleanup` whilst **Tableau Server Stopped** all log files are removed from

   `ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau Server\data\tabsvc\logs`

   but not from

   `ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau Server\logs`
2. Maybe, the backup which was generated during the upgrade might have taken some space. They usually occupy good amount. (**I suspect this is the issue**)
3. Try searching with .tsbak in Tableau folder

EDIT: -

When you run `tabadmin cleanup` whilst **running Tableau Server**

4. Active logs and log files from ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau Server\logs **are not removed**.
5. Temporary files **are not removed**.
6. Files that are in use (that is, locked by the operating system) **are not removed**.

Comment: Hi @PirateX Thanks for the reply.

I've done research already on `tabadmin cleanup` Those aren't the directories that are taking up space. I've edited for my question for clarification by adding two images.

Comment: @AndrewJacksonZA search the folder for `.tsbak` files. Also, ziplogs & bins get stored in that folder. See if that helps